# Add attribute value right below border of HTML element with JavaScript/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write JS to check the DOM for any elements with a specific custom attribute `example-type` and then add CSS to draw a border around that element then write the value of `example-type` attribute below the button right against the border.

The part I'm getting stuck is with the CSS to push the text against border and to sit on top of other elements if they they are close (not push things down).

```
<button example-type="hello" example-thing="world" example-name="alice">
  Button
</button><br>

<a href="www.google.com"class="centered" example-type="link">search</a>
<br>
<a href="testing.com"class="centered">test</a>


var el = document.querySelectorAll('[example-type]')

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].setAttribute("style","border:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#FF0000;")
  var exampleTypeValue = el[i].getAttribute("example-type")
  //add value right below the border of the element 
}
```

I can get it to where it adds the border but and can grab the element value but not sure how to add it to look like this:

*Notice the red box with white text right below the border*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `padding` attribute.

The CSS padding properties are used to generate space around an element's content, inside of any defined borders.

Code you can use

```
el[i].setAttribute("style","border:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#FF0000;padding:10px")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, Here I have used absolute divs for the same.

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll('[example-type]')

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {

  el[i].classList.add("borderBox");


  var exampleTypeValue = el[i].getAttribute("example-type")
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = exampleTypeValue;
  div.style.top = el[i].offsetTop + el[i].offsetHeight + "px";
  div.style.left = el[i].offsetLeft + "px";
  div.classList.add("absDiv")

  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
  //add value right below the border of the element 
}
```

```css
.borderBox {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FF0000;
  margin: 15px;
}

.absDiv {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button example-type="hello" example-thing="world" example-name="alice">
  Button
</button>

<a href="www.google.com" class="centered" example-type="link">search</a>

<a href="testing.com" class="centered">test</a>
```